# Union of string and Avg function in mysql showing some junk value

Tags: mysql, sql

**Mysql SQL Quires and Output**

**Query 1:**
 [image]

**Query 2:**
[image]

**Union of above two queries:**

[image]

**Expected output:**

[image]

Comment: You cannot mix different datatypes and queries are not meant to output your headers. They are part of the presentation layer, not the data layer.

Comment: Can we convert the data type? avg function return to varchar2? @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: Do *not* post pictures of code.  Copy/paste your code into your question (with proper formatting)

Comment: Sure you can change the type, but why would you?

Comment: Data vs metadata.

Comment: Want generate csv from this query. First row will be the header of the csv.

Comment: Use cast and change all int and decimal to varchar and union them

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is in the call of the sql function in the query, Try with this:

```
SELECT 'MEAN','STANDARD_DEVATION','MAX','MIN','VARIANCE'
UNION
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT AVG('MetricValue'),STDDEV_SAMP('MetricValue'),MAX('MetricValue'),
MIN('MetricValue'),VAR_SAMP('MetricValue')
FROM 'XR_METRIC_ANALYSIS' ) as temp
```

This is a possible solution